# How to add _ between group of digits in YAML using Python's PyYAML

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

In Python, you can make numbers more readable by adding `_` between group of digits:

```py
x = 1_234_567
```

However dumping with YAML will not do the same:

```py
import yaml
yaml.dump(1_234_567) # => "1234567"
```

Can I make PyYAML print numbers with the digits nicely grouped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the behaviour of PyYAML for any type by adding a [representer](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation):

```py
import re
import yaml

def pretty_print_int(n):
    return re.sub(r"(?!^)(?=(?:...)+$)", "_", str(n))

def represent_int(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_scalar("tag:yaml.org,2002:int", pretty_print_int(data))

yaml.add_representer(int, represent_int)
```

The magic `tag:yaml.org,2002:int` value is taken from the [YAML spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2803828) and known to PyYAML.

PyYAML will load the generated YAML successfully. Formatting numbers with underscores conforms to the [YAML 1.1 spec](https://yaml.org/type/int.html) but not to the YAML 1.2 spec, so some other parsers might have problems with it.

Comment: Just a note: integers with underscores conform to the [YAML 1.1 spec for int](https://yaml.org/type/int.html). So all parsers which implement 1.1 can read it correctly. You linked to the 1.2 spec.